# Laravel Mailables - Send Collection to View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using [Laravel 5.4 Mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail) and cannot pass data from my collection to the view.

I have a collection of `$users`:

```
[
  0 => {
    "name": "Justin",
    "email": "justin@test.com",
    "passwordExpires": "7 days"
  }
  1 => {
    "name": "Max",
    "email": "max@test.com",
    "passwordExpires": "2 days"
  }   
]
```

Call mailable with a collection of users:

```
 Mail::to($users)->send(new PasswordExpiring());
```

But `PasswordExpiring()` does not have access to the current user being emailed. I could pass all users in the constructor but I have no way of knowing which one Mail is trying to send to.

How would I pass the current user data into my mailable view?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this? i have the same question.

Comment: I added my answer below @split19

Comment: Thanks @Justin. That's what I ended up doing too.

Comment: Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a for loop and send the emails one at a time.

```
$users = $this->repo->getExpiring();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $mail_user = $this->transform($user);
    Mail::to($mail_user)->send(new PasswordExpiring($mail_user));
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way?